# Helper files inside three tier architecture Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, three-tier

I have a project with three tier Implemented. Now I need to add some general helper files to this project.

Example - Class to send mails.

This helper files will be used all over the project irrespective of data layer or BLogic Layer. Now I am confused. Where does I add this Helper files ? Means in which layer I need to include them.

And I want to implement some Interfaces also. In this case too I am confuced, where to add them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always put Helpers with common functionality that other projects need, in a separate project called Common. In this case you can ensure loosely coupling these helpers from certain projects.